# Unpivot pivot for transpose

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a `Accounts` table in format  `[account name]`, `Q1`, `Q2` ....`QN`   with revenue details against each account. Need to transpose it  as `[Quarter ]` `[account1]` `[account2]`  .

My query as below .

```
Select [Quarters], [account 1], [ account2] 
from 
( 
  Select * 
  from Accounts
  unpivot 
  ( Value for [Quarters] in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,.....) 
  ) unpiv
) as src
Pivot
(
   sum(value) for [Account name] in ([account1],[account2])
) piv
```

But this query is returning NULLs.

Accounts table

```
[Account name] [Q1] [Q2] [Q3]
   Apple        20   30   40
   Google       30   10   15
    IBM         34   23   12
```

desired output

```
[Quarters] [Apple][Google][IBM]
   Q1       20     30      34
   Q2       30     10      23
   Q3       40     15      12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT function to return your result.  I'm not sure why you would be returning nulls, it could be that you are including too many columns inside your subquery. To get the result you should be able to use:

```
select quarters, Apple, Google, IBM
from
(
  select accountname, quarters, value
  from accounts
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for quarters in (Q1, Q2, Q3)
  ) u
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for accountname in (Apple, Google, IBM)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c26e5/2)